# Data Tables warning: table= examples - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1

Tags: mysql, datatables

help please what should i do to this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
```

this is my table ,,,, it the errorsaid Data Tables warning: table= examples - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1 what is the best soulution for this?

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Date Register</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
       $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
       while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo"<tr>
                <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['contact']."</td>
                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                <td>".$row['password']."</td>
                <td>".$row['RegisterDate']."</td>
                <td align='center'><a href='admin.php?epr=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a> |
                    <a href='admin.php?epr=update&id=".$row['id']."'>UPDATE</a>
                </td>
                <tr>";
       }
      ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use mysqli(mysql-improved).

Comment: I think you just need to end your "<tr>"  at the end there change "<tr>" to "</tr>"

Answer (score 0):

why you are going to use `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))` replace it by
`while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))`.

Use the following loop if not works comment...

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM user");//$connection is mysqli_connection object
       while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            echo"<tr>
                <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['contact']."</td>
                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                <td>".$row['password']."</td>
                <td>".$row['RegisterDate']."</td>
                <td align='center'><a href='admin.php?epr=delete&id=".$row[id]."'>DELETE</a> |
                    <a href='admin.php?epr=update&id=".$row[id]."'>UPDATE</a>
                </td>
                <tr>";
       }
```